# React Native SectionList re-renders same data multiple times

Tags: react-native, render, react-native-sectionlist

I am running into an issue that I cannot figure out whether it's my fault or if it's a correct behavior.

I am rendering some data using React Native's SectionList component, having a structure as follows:

```
const CATEGORIES = [
  {
    id: 1, title: "LABEL C:1", data: [
      { id: 11, name: "LABEL C:1 S:11" },
      { id: 12, name: "LABEL C:1 S:12" },
      { id: 13, name: "LABEL C:1 S:13" },
      // ... more items
    ]
  },
  // ... more items
];
```

Then, the component that handles it all is as follows:

```
//
// const CATEGORIES = [ ... ];

class CategoriesAndSubcategories extends React.Component{
  keyExtractor = (item, idx) => {
    console.log("key extractor", JSON.stringify(item));
    return item.id;
  };

  renderItem = (props) => {
    return <Text>{props.item.name}</Text>;
  }

  renderSectionHeader = (props) => {
    return <Text>{props.section.title}</Text>;
  }

  render = () => {
    console.log("STARTED RENDER");

    const CATEGORIES = this.props.categories;

    return <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#FFF" }}>
      <SectionList
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow:1 }}
        sections={CATEGORIES}
        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
      />
    </View>
  };
};
```

The thing I have noticed happening is that I get `console.log`s for the same items multiple times for a single render. I have placed a console.log in the keyExtractor method, but the same situation is reproducible using any rendering method (`renderItem` or `renderSectionHeader`).
The class (CategoriesAndSubcategories) component's render method is only triggered once, as proven by the console.log at the beginning of the render method.

However, have a look at the logs I am getting in the console:

```
STARTED RENDER
key extractor {"id":1,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:1"}
key extractor {"id":2,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:2"}
key extractor {"id":3,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:3"}
key extractor {"id":4,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:4"}
key extractor {"id":5,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:5"}
key extractor {"id":6,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:6"}
key extractor {"id":7,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:7"}
key extractor {"id":8,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:8"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":1,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:1"}
key extractor {"id":2,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:2"}
key extractor {"id":1,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:1"}
key extractor {"id":3,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:3"}
key extractor {"id":2,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:2"}
key extractor {"id":4,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:4"}
key extractor {"id":3,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:3"}
key extractor {"id":5,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:5"}
key extractor {"id":4,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:4"}
key extractor {"id":6,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:6"}
key extractor {"id":5,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:5"}
key extractor {"id":7,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:7"}
key extractor {"id":6,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:6"}
key extractor {"id":8,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:8"}
key extractor {"id":7,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:7"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":8,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:8"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":1,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:1"}
key extractor {"id":2,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:2"}
key extractor {"id":3,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:3"}
key extractor {"id":4,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:4"}
key extractor {"id":5,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:5"}
key extractor {"id":6,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:6"}
key extractor {"id":7,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:7"}
key extractor {"id":8,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:8"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":10,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:10"}
key extractor {"id":11,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:11"}
key extractor {"id":12,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:12"}
key extractor {"id":13,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:13"}
key extractor {"id":14,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:14"}
key extractor {"id":15,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:15"}
key extractor {"id":16,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:16"}
key extractor {"id":17,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:17"}
key extractor {"id":18,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:18"}
key extractor {"id":19,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:19"}
key extractor {"id":20,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:20"}
key extractor {"id":21,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:21"}
key extractor {"id":22,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:22"}
key extractor {"id":23,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:23"}
key extractor {"id":24,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:24"}
key extractor {"id":25,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:25"}
key extractor {"id":26,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:26"}
key extractor {"id":27,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:27"}
key extractor {"id":28,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:28"}
key extractor {"id":29,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:29"}
key extractor {"id":30,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:30"}
key extractor {"id":31,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:31"}
key extractor {"id":32,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:32"}
key extractor {"id":33,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:33"}
key extractor {"id":34,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:34"}
key extractor {"id":35,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:35"}
key extractor {"id":36,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:36"}
key extractor {"id":37,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:37"}
key extractor {"id":38,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:38"}
key extractor {"id":39,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:39"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":41,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:41"}
key extractor {"id":42,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:42"}
key extractor {"id":43,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:43"}
key extractor {"id":44,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:44"}
key extractor {"id":45,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:45"}
key extractor {"id":46,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:46"}
key extractor {"id":47,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:47"}
key extractor {"id":48,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:48"}
key extractor {"id":49,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:49"}
key extractor {"id":50,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:50"}
key extractor {"id":51,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:51"}
key extractor {"id":52,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:52"}
key extractor {"id":53,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:53"}
key extractor {"id":54,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:54"}
key extractor {"id":55,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:55"}
key extractor {"id":57,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:57"}
key extractor {"id":58,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:58"}
key extractor {"id":59,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:59"}
key extractor {"id":60,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:60"}
key extractor {"id":61,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:61"}
key extractor {"id":62,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:62"}
key extractor {"id":63,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:63"}
key extractor {"id":64,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:64"}
key extractor {"id":65,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:65"}
key extractor {"id":66,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:66"}
key extractor {"id":67,"name":"LABEL C:4 S:67"}
key extractor {"id":68,"name":"LABEL C:4 S:68"}
key extractor {"id":69,"name":"LABEL C:4 S:69"}
key extractor {"id":70,"name":"LABEL C:4 S:70"}
key extractor {"id":71,"name":"LABEL C:4 S:71"}
key extractor {"id":72,"name":"LABEL C:4 S:72"}
key extractor {"id":88,"name":"LABEL C:4 S:88"}
key extractor {"id":73,"name":"LABEL C:5 S:73"}
key extractor {"id":74,"name":"LABEL C:5 S:74"}
key extractor {"id":75,"name":"LABEL C:5 S:75"}
key extractor {"id":76,"name":"LABEL C:5 S:76"}
key extractor {"id":77,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:77"}
key extractor {"id":78,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:78"}
key extractor {"id":79,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:79"}
key extractor {"id":80,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:80"}
key extractor {"id":81,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:81"}
key extractor {"id":82,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:82"}
key extractor {"id":83,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:83"}
key extractor {"id":84,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:84"}
key extractor {"id":85,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:85"}
key extractor {"id":1,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:1"}
key extractor {"id":2,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:2"}
key extractor {"id":3,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:3"}
key extractor {"id":4,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:4"}
key extractor {"id":5,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:5"}
key extractor {"id":6,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:6"}
key extractor {"id":7,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:7"}
key extractor {"id":8,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:8"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":10,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:10"}
key extractor {"id":11,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:11"}
key extractor {"id":12,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:12"}
key extractor {"id":13,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:13"}
key extractor {"id":14,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:14"}
key extractor {"id":15,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:15"}
key extractor {"id":16,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:16"}
key extractor {"id":17,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:17"}
key extractor {"id":18,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:18"}
key extractor {"id":19,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:19"}
key extractor {"id":20,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:20"}
key extractor {"id":21,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:21"}
key extractor {"id":22,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:22"}
key extractor {"id":23,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:23"}
key extractor {"id":24,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:24"}
key extractor {"id":25,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:25"}
key extractor {"id":26,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:26"}
key extractor {"id":27,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:27"}
key extractor {"id":28,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:28"}
key extractor {"id":29,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:29"}
key extractor {"id":30,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:30"}
key extractor {"id":30,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:30"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":1,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:1"}
key extractor {"id":2,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:2"}
key extractor {"id":1,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:1"}
key extractor {"id":3,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:3"}
key extractor {"id":2,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:2"}
key extractor {"id":4,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:4"}
key extractor {"id":3,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:3"}
key extractor {"id":5,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:5"}
key extractor {"id":4,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:4"}
key extractor {"id":6,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:6"}
key extractor {"id":5,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:5"}
key extractor {"id":7,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:7"}
key extractor {"id":6,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:6"}
key extractor {"id":8,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:8"}
key extractor {"id":7,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:7"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":8,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:8"}
key extractor {"id":10,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:10"}
key extractor {"id":11,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:11"}
key extractor {"id":10,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:10"}
key extractor {"id":12,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:12"}
key extractor {"id":11,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:11"}
key extractor {"id":13,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:13"}
key extractor {"id":12,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:12"}
key extractor {"id":14,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:14"}
key extractor {"id":15,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:15"}
key extractor {"id":14,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:14"}
key extractor {"id":16,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:16"}
key extractor {"id":15,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:15"}
key extractor {"id":17,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:17"}
key extractor {"id":16,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:16"}
key extractor {"id":18,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:18"}
key extractor {"id":17,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:17"}
key extractor {"id":19,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:19"}
key extractor {"id":18,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:18"}
key extractor {"id":20,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:20"}
key extractor {"id":19,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:19"}
key extractor {"id":21,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:21"}
key extractor {"id":20,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:20"}
key extractor {"id":22,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:22"}
key extractor {"id":21,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:21"}
key extractor {"id":23,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:23"}
key extractor {"id":22,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:22"}
key extractor {"id":24,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:24"}
key extractor {"id":23,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:23"}
key extractor {"id":25,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:25"}
key extractor {"id":24,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:24"}
key extractor {"id":26,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:26"}
key extractor {"id":25,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:25"}
key extractor {"id":27,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:27"}
key extractor {"id":26,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:26"}
key extractor {"id":28,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:28"}
key extractor {"id":27,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:27"}
key extractor {"id":29,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:29"}
key extractor {"id":28,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:28"}
key extractor {"id":30,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:30"}
key extractor {"id":29,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:29"}
key extractor {"id":30,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:30"}
key extractor {"id":30,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:30"}
key extractor {"id":1,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:1"}
key extractor {"id":2,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:2"}
key extractor {"id":3,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:3"}
key extractor {"id":4,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:4"}
key extractor {"id":5,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:5"}
key extractor {"id":6,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:6"}
key extractor {"id":7,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:7"}
key extractor {"id":8,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:8"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":10,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:10"}
key extractor {"id":11,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:11"}
key extractor {"id":12,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:12"}
key extractor {"id":13,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:13"}
key extractor {"id":14,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:14"}
key extractor {"id":15,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:15"}
key extractor {"id":16,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:16"}
key extractor {"id":17,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:17"}
key extractor {"id":18,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:18"}
key extractor {"id":19,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:19"}
key extractor {"id":20,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:20"}
key extractor {"id":21,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:21"}
key extractor {"id":22,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:22"}
key extractor {"id":23,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:23"}
key extractor {"id":24,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:24"}
key extractor {"id":25,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:25"}
key extractor {"id":26,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:26"}
key extractor {"id":27,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:27"}
key extractor {"id":28,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:28"}
key extractor {"id":29,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:29"}
key extractor {"id":30,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:30"}
key extractor {"id":31,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:31"}
key extractor {"id":32,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:32"}
key extractor {"id":33,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:33"}
key extractor {"id":34,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:34"}
key extractor {"id":35,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:35"}
key extractor {"id":36,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:36"}
key extractor {"id":37,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:37"}
key extractor {"id":38,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:38"}
key extractor {"id":39,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:39"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":41,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:41"}
key extractor {"id":42,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:42"}
key extractor {"id":43,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:43"}
key extractor {"id":44,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:44"}
key extractor {"id":45,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:45"}
key extractor {"id":46,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:46"}
key extractor {"id":47,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:47"}
key extractor {"id":48,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:48"}
key extractor {"id":49,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:49"}
key extractor {"id":50,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:50"}
key extractor {"id":51,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:51"}
key extractor {"id":52,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:52"}
key extractor {"id":53,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:53"}
key extractor {"id":54,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:54"}
key extractor {"id":55,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:55"}
key extractor {"id":57,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:57"}
key extractor {"id":58,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:58"}
key extractor {"id":59,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:59"}
key extractor {"id":60,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:60"}
key extractor {"id":61,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:61"}
key extractor {"id":62,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:62"}
key extractor {"id":63,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:63"}
key extractor {"id":64,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:64"}
key extractor {"id":65,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:65"}
key extractor {"id":66,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:66"}
key extractor {"id":67,"name":"LABEL C:4 S:67"}
key extractor {"id":68,"name":"LABEL C:4 S:68"}
key extractor {"id":69,"name":"LABEL C:4 S:69"}
key extractor {"id":70,"name":"LABEL C:4 S:70"}
key extractor {"id":71,"name":"LABEL C:4 S:71"}
key extractor {"id":72,"name":"LABEL C:4 S:72"}
key extractor {"id":88,"name":"LABEL C:4 S:88"}
key extractor {"id":73,"name":"LABEL C:5 S:73"}
key extractor {"id":74,"name":"LABEL C:5 S:74"}
key extractor {"id":75,"name":"LABEL C:5 S:75"}
key extractor {"id":76,"name":"LABEL C:5 S:76"}
key extractor {"id":77,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:77"}
key extractor {"id":78,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:78"}
key extractor {"id":79,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:79"}
key extractor {"id":80,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:80"}
key extractor {"id":81,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:81"}
key extractor {"id":82,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:82"}
key extractor {"id":83,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:83"}
key extractor {"id":84,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:84"}
key extractor {"id":85,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:85"}
key extractor {"id":1,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:1"}
key extractor {"id":2,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:2"}
key extractor {"id":3,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:3"}
key extractor {"id":4,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:4"}
key extractor {"id":5,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:5"}
key extractor {"id":6,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:6"}
key extractor {"id":7,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:7"}
key extractor {"id":8,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:8"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":10,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:10"}
key extractor {"id":11,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:11"}
key extractor {"id":12,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:12"}
key extractor {"id":13,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:13"}
key extractor {"id":14,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:14"}
key extractor {"id":15,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:15"}
key extractor {"id":16,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:16"}
key extractor {"id":17,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:17"}
key extractor {"id":18,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:18"}
key extractor {"id":19,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:19"}
key extractor {"id":20,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:20"}
key extractor {"id":21,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:21"}
key extractor {"id":22,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:22"}
key extractor {"id":23,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:23"}
key extractor {"id":24,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:24"}
key extractor {"id":25,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:25"}
key extractor {"id":26,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:26"}
key extractor {"id":27,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:27"}
key extractor {"id":28,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:28"}
key extractor {"id":29,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:29"}
key extractor {"id":30,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:30"}
key extractor {"id":31,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:31"}
key extractor {"id":32,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:32"}
key extractor {"id":33,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:33"}
key extractor {"id":34,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:34"}
key extractor {"id":35,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:35"}
key extractor {"id":36,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:36"}
key extractor {"id":37,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:37"}
key extractor {"id":38,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:38"}
key extractor {"id":39,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:39"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":1,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:1"}
key extractor {"id":2,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:2"}
key extractor {"id":1,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:1"}
key extractor {"id":3,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:3"}
key extractor {"id":2,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:2"}
key extractor {"id":4,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:4"}
key extractor {"id":3,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:3"}
key extractor {"id":5,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:5"}
key extractor {"id":4,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:4"}
key extractor {"id":6,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:6"}
key extractor {"id":5,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:5"}
key extractor {"id":7,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:7"}
key extractor {"id":6,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:6"}
key extractor {"id":8,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:8"}
key extractor {"id":7,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:7"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":8,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:8"}
key extractor {"id":10,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:10"}
key extractor {"id":11,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:11"}
key extractor {"id":10,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:10"}
key extractor {"id":12,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:12"}
key extractor {"id":11,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:11"}
key extractor {"id":13,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:13"}
key extractor {"id":12,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:12"}
key extractor {"id":14,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:14"}
key extractor {"id":15,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:15"}
key extractor {"id":14,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:14"}
key extractor {"id":16,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:16"}
key extractor {"id":15,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:15"}
key extractor {"id":17,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:17"}
key extractor {"id":16,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:16"}
key extractor {"id":18,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:18"}
key extractor {"id":17,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:17"}
key extractor {"id":19,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:19"}
key extractor {"id":18,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:18"}
key extractor {"id":20,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:20"}
key extractor {"id":19,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:19"}
key extractor {"id":21,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:21"}
key extractor {"id":20,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:20"}
key extractor {"id":22,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:22"}
key extractor {"id":21,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:21"}
key extractor {"id":23,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:23"}
key extractor {"id":22,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:22"}
key extractor {"id":24,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:24"}
key extractor {"id":23,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:23"}
key extractor {"id":25,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:25"}
key extractor {"id":24,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:24"}
key extractor {"id":26,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:26"}
key extractor {"id":25,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:25"}
key extractor {"id":27,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:27"}
key extractor {"id":26,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:26"}
key extractor {"id":28,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:28"}
key extractor {"id":27,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:27"}
key extractor {"id":29,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:29"}
key extractor {"id":28,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:28"}
key extractor {"id":30,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:30"}
key extractor {"id":29,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:29"}
key extractor {"id":31,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:31"}
key extractor {"id":30,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:30"}
key extractor {"id":32,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:32"}
key extractor {"id":31,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:31"}
key extractor {"id":33,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:33"}
key extractor {"id":32,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:32"}
key extractor {"id":34,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:34"}
key extractor {"id":33,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:33"}
key extractor {"id":35,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:35"}
key extractor {"id":34,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:34"}
key extractor {"id":36,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:36"}
key extractor {"id":35,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:35"}
key extractor {"id":37,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:37"}
key extractor {"id":36,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:36"}
key extractor {"id":38,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:38"}
key extractor {"id":37,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:37"}
key extractor {"id":39,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:39"}
key extractor {"id":38,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:38"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":39,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:39"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":1,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:1"}
key extractor {"id":2,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:2"}
key extractor {"id":3,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:3"}
key extractor {"id":4,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:4"}
key extractor {"id":5,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:5"}
key extractor {"id":6,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:6"}
key extractor {"id":7,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:7"}
key extractor {"id":8,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:8"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":10,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:10"}
key extractor {"id":11,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:11"}
key extractor {"id":12,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:12"}
key extractor {"id":13,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:13"}
key extractor {"id":14,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:14"}
key extractor {"id":15,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:15"}
key extractor {"id":16,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:16"}
key extractor {"id":17,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:17"}
key extractor {"id":18,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:18"}
key extractor {"id":19,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:19"}
key extractor {"id":20,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:20"}
key extractor {"id":21,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:21"}
key extractor {"id":22,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:22"}
key extractor {"id":23,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:23"}
key extractor {"id":24,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:24"}
key extractor {"id":25,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:25"}
key extractor {"id":26,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:26"}
key extractor {"id":27,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:27"}
key extractor {"id":28,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:28"}
key extractor {"id":29,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:29"}
key extractor {"id":30,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:30"}
key extractor {"id":31,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:31"}
key extractor {"id":32,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:32"}
key extractor {"id":33,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:33"}
key extractor {"id":34,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:34"}
key extractor {"id":35,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:35"}
key extractor {"id":36,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:36"}
key extractor {"id":37,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:37"}
key extractor {"id":38,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:38"}
key extractor {"id":39,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:39"}
key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}
key extractor {"id":41,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:41"}
key extractor {"id":42,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:42"}
key extractor {"id":43,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:43"}
key extractor {"id":44,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:44"}
key extractor {"id":45,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:45"}
key extractor {"id":46,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:46"}
key extractor {"id":47,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:47"}
key extractor {"id":48,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:48"}
key extractor {"id":49,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:49"}
key extractor {"id":50,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:50"}
key extractor {"id":51,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:51"}
key extractor {"id":52,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:52"}
key extractor {"id":53,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:53"}
key extractor {"id":54,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:54"}
key extractor {"id":55,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:55"}
key extractor {"id":57,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:57"}
key extractor {"id":58,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:58"}
key extractor {"id":59,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:59"}
key extractor {"id":60,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:60"}
key extractor {"id":61,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:61"}
key extractor {"id":62,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:62"}
key extractor {"id":63,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:63"}
key extractor {"id":64,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:64"}
key extractor {"id":65,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:65"}
key extractor {"id":66,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:66"}
key extractor {"id":67,"name":"LABEL C:4 S:67"}
key extractor {"id":68,"name":"LABEL C:4 S:68"}
key extractor {"id":69,"name":"LABEL C:4 S:69"}
key extractor {"id":70,"name":"LABEL C:4 S:70"}
key extractor {"id":71,"name":"LABEL C:4 S:71"}
key extractor {"id":72,"name":"LABEL C:4 S:72"}
key extractor {"id":88,"name":"LABEL C:4 S:88"}
key extractor {"id":73,"name":"LABEL C:5 S:73"}
key extractor {"id":74,"name":"LABEL C:5 S:74"}
key extractor {"id":75,"name":"LABEL C:5 S:75"}
key extractor {"id":76,"name":"LABEL C:5 S:76"}
key extractor {"id":77,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:77"}
key extractor {"id":78,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:78"}
key extractor {"id":79,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:79"}
key extractor {"id":80,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:80"}
key extractor {"id":81,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:81"}
key extractor {"id":82,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:82"}
key extractor {"id":83,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:83"}
key extractor {"id":84,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:84"}
key extractor {"id":85,"name":"LABEL C:6 S:85"}
key extractor {"id":1,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:1"}
key extractor {"id":2,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:2"}
key extractor {"id":3,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:3"}
key extractor {"id":4,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:4"}
key extractor {"id":5,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:5"}
key extractor {"id":6,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:6"}
key extractor {"id":7,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:7"}
key extractor {"id":8,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:8"}
key extractor {"id":9,"name":"LABEL C:1 S:9"}
key extractor {"id":10,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:10"}
key extractor {"id":11,"name":"LABEL C:2 S:11"}

... due to StackOverflow's character limit per-post, I cannot post the full log
... however, the same 'key extractor' logs continue about 5 times more than what posted here
```

I am not trying to mock you or anything, these are the exact logs I get on this component's first and only render. Each item in the SectionList is re-rendered 10+ times before the SectionList render comes to a stop. While rendering no data is updated in the `CATEGORIES` array, no layout changes happen in the outside containers, no scroll is happening in the SectionList's UI. Also, it seems that items are 'randomly' re-rendered, as you can see in the logs, the item `key extractor {"id":40,"name":"LABEL C:3 S:40"}` appears for 38 consecutive times (at about 70% of the logs list), while other times a render seems like interrupted half-way through, and restarts from the beginning.

Does anyone have any idea why so many re-renders happen with this code? Am I doing anything wrong?

p.s. I am using Expo SDK36, React 16.9, React Native 0.61.4, React Navigation 5 (5.0.5 at the moment). Behavior is the same on iOS (10+) and Android (9).